# Не отображается маршрут на Яндекс-Картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

создаю карту с маршрутом по примеру из песочницы:

```
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: [
            [55.734876, 37.59308],
            "Москва, ул. Мясницкая"
        ],
        params: {
            results: 1
        }
    }, {
        boundsAutoApply: true
    });

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.750625, 37.626],
        zoom: 7,
        controls: []
    }, {
        buttonMaxWidth: 300
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
```

в результате маршрут как бы создался, но он как будто прозрачен. т.е. если точно попасть в линию маршрута мышкой, то покажется всплывающее окно с расстоянием и временем, но самой линии маршрута нет.

[image: скриншот]

указывать цвет линии бесполезно. если распечатать сегменты маршрута, то все ок, ошибок нет, сегменты все есть. кнопка "открыть маршрут" открывает в новом окне карту и там маршрут рисуется нормально, линия есть. может быть кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Дайте ссылку на страницу с проблемой или пример на jsfiddle. Так могут ломать карту CSS-стили страницы (они не должны действовать на область карты).

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Оказывается яндекс карты рисуются с помощью svg, а в css стояло переопределение ширины всех svg =100%. Из-за этого все ломалось!

Answer (score 1):

проблема была в css. В одной из них стояло переопределение

```
svg{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

стоило убрать и маршрут нарисовался!

Comment: Хочешь сказать, маршрут рисуется в отдельном svg-теге?

Comment: Графика в API рисуется через svg, если в глобальных стилях страницы есть правила, которые влияют на карту, они также могу влиять и на отображение svg. Так что нормальный ответ.